# Axios Call returns error 401 - after refreshing everything's fine

Tags: odata, axios

I'm doing an axios call.

My Code:

```
loginSAP () {
  var config = {
    url: 'http://linkToSAPoDataService/oDataSet?&format=json',
    withCredentials: true
  }
  this.axios(config)
}
```

Need to login first to access my database.

After I log in, I get:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 401 (Unauthorized)
createError.js:15 Uncaught (in promise) Error: Request failed with status code 401
    at createError (createError.js:15)
    at settle (settle.js:18)
    at XMLHttpRequest.handleLoad (xhr.js:77)
```

I can't access the data instantly - 
**When I refresh the page, everything's fine and working.**

I have to access and display the data **before** refreshing.

Do you have any ideas what could be wrong with my call?

Answer (score 0):

Seems that your axios config is not going to be updated after login. You can use an interceptor to add login token (as an example) to axios config.

```
axios
  .interceptors
  .request
  .use(function (config) {
    if (cookie.load('auth-token')) {
      config.headers['AUTH-TOKEN'] = cookie.load('auth-token');
    }
    return config;
  }, function (error) {
    return Promise.reject(error);
  });
```

Therefore, after login, all of your requests have a valid token with no need to refresh the page to reset the config.